# How do I solve the error, filter() is not a function

Tags: javascript

Here is what I tried. Also `order` is part of a query so this works, I am just not posting the rest of the code so it doesn't get messy. I was getting errors on the `paymentsResults[i].filter()` saying it is not function . Anyways, if there is a better way to write it, please let me know. Appreciate it.

```
 const getCatType = order => {
  if (
    order.type === "Invoice" ||
    order.type === "One-time" ||
    order.type === "Free"

  ) {
    return "Once";
  } else if (order.type === "Semester") {
    return "Recurring";
  }
};

for (let i = 0; i < paymentsResults.length; i++) {
const paymentsOnce = paymentsResults[i].filter(o => getCatType(o) === "Once");
}
```

Comment: seems like `paymentsResults[i]` is not of type Array.

Comment: No loop `const paymentsOnce = paymentsResults.filter(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Using a `switch` would be more useful. And then all you need to do it `filter` out the objects where they match - no need for an additional loop.

```js
function getCatType(order) {
  switch(order.type) {
    case 'Invoice':
    case 'One-time':
    case 'Free': return 'Once';
    case 'Semester': return 'Recurring';
    default: return null;
  }
}

const paymentsResults = [
  { type: 'Invoice', id: 1 },
  { type: 'Semester', id: 2 },
  { type: 'Free', id: 3 },
  { type: 'One-time', id: 4 }
];

function typeOfPayment(type) {
  return paymentsResults.filter(order => {
    return getCatType(order) === type;
  });
}

console.log(typeOfPayment('Once'));
console.log(typeOfPayment('Recurring'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce and also you can check for the types you need directly in the reduce cb, mix this with a regex and you can extract what ever types of orders you want by creating a simple array with the types you need. Assuming your paymentsResults are something like this array you can do this:

```js
const paymentsResults = [

  {
    order: {
      type: 'Invoice',
      total: 10
    },
    price: 2
  },
  {
    order: {
      type: 'One-time',
      total: 11
    }
  },
  {
    order: {
      type: 'Free',
      total: 12
    }
  },
  {
    order: {
      type: 'Semester',
      total: 13
    }
  },
];

let extract = ['Invoice', 'One-time', 'Free'];
const regex = new RegExp(extract.join('|'), 'i');
let paymentsOnce = paymentsResults.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if (regex.test(obj.order.type)) acc.push(obj);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(paymentsOnce);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are confused with what [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is actually supposed to do.

filter() is an Array-Function iterating over the given Array and returning the objects that fit the filter-conditions defined in the callback function.

Therefore you don't need the for-Loop to get into each Item of your array, but simply call your filter-function on the array itself.

This only applies if you have an Array of Objects with the key `type` in paymentsResults. Sadly you didn't provide your origin data-structure.
If it is not like I assumed, then please comment down below, what your data structure looks like.

```
for (let i = 0; i < paymentsResults.length; i++) {
const paymentsOnce = paymentsResults[i].filter(o => getCatType(o) === "Once");
}
```

Will become:

```
// ONLY GIVEN IF YOUR STRUCTURE LOOKS LIKE 
// paymentsResults = [{type: 'Thing'}, {type: 'Thing'}, ...];
const paymentsOnce = paymentsResults.filter(o => getCatType(o) === "Once");
```